# How to prevent Hangfire from running a job twice in staging server?

Tags: hangfire

I have created a project on .net core 2.0. In my project there is a requirement i.e

In 11 AM & 5 PM I need to send Mail & Message to user in every day.

I have successfully configure Hangfire in my project & it’s working perfectly in staging server.

My main problem is when the job will run it will send two times mail & message to user.

Can some one help me regarding this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKe86.png)

I am trying to send mail & message one time